# Html change background/text colors when printing

Tags: html, printing, colors, background

I'm having trouble with a print in html, because my background color web-site is black and when window.print() is activated i need the background color switched to white.

How can I do this? considering Time X Work.
I´ve tried to change Css, transform to PDF and others.

I can´t use PHP.

Comment: Just to clarify... Do you have a separate stylesheet or separate style rules within your stylesheet for printing?  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

Comment: I created another css, just for print.

Comment: In what way is this not working, then?  Did you set the background to be white in the print stylesheet?

Comment: Yes i insert this value to background... 

Thanks for help

Comment: That looks correct.  Can you do some debugging to find out what's not working?  There are various browser-based tools (such as FireBug, I think.  Or at least the Web Developer Toolbar in Firefox) which can mimic a media type to help debug CSS.  Or could you provide more complete code (minimally reproducing the issue) or an online example?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this in a stylesheet with an @media print directive.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a separate stylesheet for printing. Take a look online at print stylesheets.

E.g. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

The key part being

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

You can then add this in the `print.css` stylesheet

```
body {
    background: white;
}
```

to get rid of the background

Comment: How i relate this with the button (in case is a image).

<div id="Print" style="position:absolute; cursor:pointer; overflow:hidden; left:'+(865*razX)+'px; text-align:center; top:'+(36*razY)+'px; height: '+(40*razY)+'px; width: '+(160*razX)+'px;"  ><img src="imagens/Print.png" onClick="window.print()" title="Imprimir" width="'+(38*razY)+'px" height="'+(38*razY)+'px"> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Print.css"></div>';



Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @user1991144: Please don't put code in comments, it's nearly impossible to read.  If there is additional information then you can edit the question to add that information.  As for what you're asking here, it looks like you're using inline styles.  This will make media-based CSS _very_ difficult.  Your styles should be in a separate stylesheet, not in the HTML markup.  Then the browser will more easily know which stylesheet to use for screen vs. print.